# What is the isomorphism $\pi_1(U(1))\cong \varinjlim_n \pi_1(U(n))$?

Tags: algebraic-topology, k-theory, unitary-matrices

I am reading about Bott Periodicity in Atiyah's "K-Theory". He states a Corollary

> $K^{-2}(point) = K^2(S^2)\cong \mathbb{Z}$, generated by the Bott generator $b$.

Then he says that

> This corollary amounts to the statement that $\pi_1(U(1))\rightarrow \varinjlim_n \pi_1(U(n))$ is an isomorphism.

I know that since $S^1$ is compact and $U(n)\subseteq U(n+1)$ is closed,  $\varinjlim_n[S^1,U(n)]\cong [S^1, U]\cong \tilde{K}(\Sigma S^1)=\tilde{K}(S^2)$. I know $\tilde{K}(S^2) = K^{-2}(point)$ is cyclic generated by $b$.

I also see why the first corollary is true since $K^{-2}(point)\cong K(point)$ by Bott periodicity, then $K(point)\cong K(S^2\times point)\cong K(S^2)\cong K^{2}(S^2)$ by more Bott periodicity.

$\pi_1(U(1))$ is certainly also $\mathbb{Z}$, so I guess I see that they are isomorphic.
But what is this map exactly, and how, precisely does it correspond to the Bott map?

Comment: I mean, doesn't $U(1)\subseteq U(n)$ automatically give a map $\pi_1(U(1))\to\pi_1(U(n))$?

Comment: Oh. I suppose so! Thanks :)
Still, I don't see in what sense these isomorphisms amount to "the same" fact... One is the map induced by inclusion, the other is a composition of some Bott maps. Could someone clarify how these two maps relate to one another?

Comment: There is a natural Iso between $\pi_1(U(1))$ and $\pi_2(BU(1))$, where the latter is generated by a certain (homotopy class of a) map $S^2 \to BU(1)$ which should classify the tautological line bundle, which should correspond to the Bott generator. Does this help?